# Region: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename

Tags: python, ioerror

I'm not sure why, but for some reason, whenever I have "region" in the file name of the output file, it gives me this error:

**IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'path\regionlog.txt'**

It does this for **"region.txt"**, **"logregion.txt"**, etc.

```
class writeTo:
    def __init__(self, stdout, name):
       self.stdout = stdout
       self.log = file(name, 'w') #here is where it says the error occurs

output = os.path.abspath('path\regionlog.txt')
writer = writeTo(sys.stdout, output) #and here too
```

Why is this? I really would like to name my file "regionlog.txt" but it keeps coming up with that error. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use forward slashes:

```
'path/regionlog.txt'
```

Or raw strings:

```
r'path\regionlog.txt'
```

Or at least escape your backslashes:

```
'path\\regionlog.txt'
```

---

`\r` is a carriage return.

---

Another option: use `os.path.join` and you won't have to worry about slashes at all:

```
output = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('path', 'regionlog.txt'))
```

Comment: third option: double the slashes.

Comment: Fourth option: use `os.path.join`. The OP already imported `os.path`.

Answer (score 1):

In C standard language, `\t`, `\n`, `\r` are escape characters. `\t` is a transverse to the next TAB position. `\n` is a newline and `\r` is a carriage return. You should use `\\r` or `/r`, and you will solve the problem!

Comment: Next time, check to make sure what you typed came out correctly on screen, as your `\\r` showed up like `\r`, which would not be at all helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Additionaly, Python also gives this message when trying to open a file > 50 MB from a SharePoint shared drive.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2668751/you-cannot-download-more-than-50-mb-or-upload-large-files-when-the-upl