# Python direct path file printing issue?

Tags: python, file, directory

So I have a script that needs to print to a file in a different directory. I give that absolute path and python doesn't like it.

Here's where the file is located: 
`C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Senior_design\QT_Library\build-TransmitterPlot-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\numbers.txt`

(I know, long path, but QT plotter makes the file names really long)

I typed:

```
textfile = open('C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Senior_design\QT_Library\build-TransmitterPlot-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\numbers.txt', 'w')
```

And I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:
```

I've read that I can use relative paths, but I am unsure how to give it a relative path with so many directories to go through.

Thanks!

Comment: Escape the backslashes in your file path.

Comment: Or use a "raw" string:  `open(r'C:\Users\...','w')`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that python is interpreting the backslashes in your path as escape sequences:

```
>>> 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Senior_design\QT_Library\build-TransmitterPlot-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\numbers.txt'
'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Senior_design\\QT_Library\x08uild-TransmitterPlot-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\numbers.txt'
```

Notice that both `\b` and `\n` get translated to something else.  Use a "raw" string instead:

```
>>> r'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Senior_design\QT_Library\build-TransmitterPlot-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\numbers.txt'
'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Senior_design\\QT_Library\\build-TransmitterPlot-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\\numbers.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141761/region-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-w-or-filename) may be of help.

Essentially, your backslashes are causing issues.